# How to keep Microsoft Edge from reloading my page as soon as memory hits the 4GB mark?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, memory-management, microsoft-edge

I'm in the process of refactoring [a demo](http://3d.luciad.com/) where +70,000 flight trajectories with approximately 3,500,000 recorded positions are loaded into a map with live 2D to 3D switching.

As you can imagine, this consumes quite a lot of memory. In fact, I'm currently hitting peaks of up to 4,25GB memory consumption in Chrome :

[image]

Unfortunately, memory consumption in Edge is even worse! Edge doesn't even get below 3,2GB after loading the data, and on average it seems to consume about 1GB more of memory in Chrome.

To make things worse, Edge can't handle 4GB of memory for one page. As soon as my memory consumption his the 4GB mark, it kills the process and starts reloading the page :

[image]

Can anyone help me come up with a way to overcome this problem in Edge without reducing the amount of data that's being loaded into the browser?

For example, is there a way to change the memory limits for Edge so it can handle pages of 4GB and up? Or what do you suggest I could try to prevent the used memory of my page from reaching the 4GB mark?

Comment: Please don't pollute an otherwise good question with additional variations of "Is there a solution to my problem?" for the sake of bumping it for views.

Comment: I don't know IE, and it's quite hard for me to test on it. Is this limit itself limited to the main thread ? If not, are Workers concerned by this limit / couldn't it be a way to split your data. And by the way, do you really have no way to only load chunks of data ? Do you really allways need all the data to be available ? Isn't it possible to create some different level of precisions in this data ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to run the demo in Edge so that you can create tests and then fix the problem? Are you sure that Edge is supported by the original product in the first place, if it's impossible to run it inside it? Also, why not develop on Chrome and then test just the refactored version inside Edge?

Comment: @Kaiido : I don't know if the limit is limited to the main thread. I can't find any documentation on this whatsoever. And no, I don't have the option of loading only chunks of data because there's no way to get [something like this](http://3d.luciad.com/) running smoothly otherwise. Also, the data is about as lightweight as it gets in the current version of our product! We already created our own custom binary format to keep the actual data transferred over HTTP as small as possible... which is still a whopping 95MB!

Comment: @Groo : The current plan is to load a reduced dataset that allows me to diagnose the problem more easily (trying to create a memory snapshot with the complete dataset crashes any browser I tried it in) and find out whether or not it is possible reduce the memory consumption without impacting the behavior of the app. Developing on Chrome is what I've done so far, until I tested the result on Edge... which does happen to be a browser we're supposed to support!

Comment: What you want to support and what you can support are often two different things.  This works fine in Chrome.  If you must support others, you might have to get crafty with server-side rendering and send them a video.

Comment: Try hiding the canvas/svg or its block parent as its being updated with the data. Are you using d3.geo? <div id="viewport" style="display:none"><svg id="globe" .....>.....</svg></div>
on loading the data and transforming the map/globe viewport.style.display="block"... 95MB of data should not consume GB of memory... It must be trying to render the data vector by vector.

Comment: @Brad : This is supposed to be an interactive demo that illustrates the capabilities of the framework that's one of the core products of the company I'm working for. Sending a video is not an option, except for non-supported browsers. I guess loading a reduced dataset (eg. 25 to 50% of the data) may be an option for MS Edge, but it's one I prefer to avoid.

Comment: @RobParsons : We're using D3 for a timechart only, but we may drop that in a future version of the demo. The map itself uses [a proprietary framework](http://www.luciad.com/solutions/luciadria) that's a core product of the company I'm working for. Actually it's two maps in the current version of my demo : a 3D map and a 2D map, sharing the same data-model, of which only one is displayed in the DOM (the other is hidden). And yeah, I do guess the data is rendered vector by vector and refreshed whenever there's movement. So you can't just delete all data after the initial load!

Comment: Hi John, the important thing is that you must hide the canvas/svg element while you are rendering/drawing the data to it....and then display it on completion... my guess the IE memory issue is caused by multiple screen redraws.... The performance tab of the dev tool should be able to monitor redraw events for U.

Comment: I don't think you need to send that much data. If Edge or Chrome is not allowing it, it probably means no one else is doing what your doing; which is probably not a good thing. I think you want to send only pertinent data through ajax requests.

Comment: @KeithBecker : Actually, only about 100 Mb of data is sent from the server to the browser (most of it in binary files to keep the transfer size as small as possible). The memory consumption is probably related to the WebGL engine powering the demo and the abstraction layers on top of it. And yes, we do need as much data as is currently being sent. Showing that our product is capable of handling that much data is kind of the point of the demo.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problems with IE and Silverlight in which the application was rendering maps, lines with animations etc. IE could not render/load/animate when the memory exceeds 1.5gb. No matter what the version of IE or Windows, the problem could not be resolved so the related bug had been marked as a COTS issue. I don't know if there is an exact memory limits (there is no related documation) but I know you cannot tune memory constraints for IE. So, you should handle this issue in your application code logics. You should figure out in what situations the problem occurs because the problem may not be the exact memory size. The problem may still exists even if you handle the issue for 4Gb limitations. By the way, the [demo application](http://3d.luciad.com/) you submitted does not support neither IE or Edge which may be due to the issues above.

Comment: The [original demo](http://3d.luciad.com/) that I'm refactoring does run fine in Edge 38, on my ZBook laptop running Windows 10. Its memory consumption is much lower, however, since it's based on a prototype that takes a few shortcuts. We would like it the demo to be ported to the latest release of our product, but the high memory consumption is problematic for not just Edge but also mobile browsers... browsers that we ARE supposed to support. Hence my question.